# How do i use use javascript on form upload button django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

**What I want to achieve:**

My requirement is to first display the image on the `template/html` page then upload it in the database, for displaying the image on the page I am using javascript.

So how do i use `{{form.image}}` in javascript button?

---

**Other side details:**

For uploading the image I am using Django forms inbuilt button of `{{form.image}}` by clicking one button I should be able to display and upload the image

Below is the code for reference

<kbd>form.py</kbd>

```
from django import forms 

from .models import Boneage

class BoneageForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta: 
        model = Boneage 
        fields = ('gender', 'age','images')
```

JavaScript code

```
<script>
      const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
      const fileName = document.querySelector(".file-name");
      const defaultBtn = document.querySelector("#default-btn");
      const customBtn = document.querySelector("#custom-btn");
      const cancelBtn = document.querySelector("#cancel-btn i");
      const img = document.querySelector("img");
      let regExp = /[0-9a-zA-Z\^\&\'\@\{\}\[\]\,\$\=\!\-\#\(\)\.\%\+\~\_ ]+$/;
      function defaultBtnActive(){
        defaultBtn.click();
      }
      defaultBtn.addEventListener("change", function(){
        const file = this.files[0];
        if(file){
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function(){
            const result = reader.result;
            img.src = result;
            wrapper.classList.add("active");
          }
          cancelBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
            img.src = "";
            wrapper.classList.remove("active");
          })
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
        if(this.value){
          let valueStore = this.value.match(regExp);
          fileName.textContent = valueStore;
        }
      });
    </script>
```

How do i use this java script code in the Django form button?

```
{{form.images}}
   <button onclick="defaultBtnActive()" id="custom-btn">  </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django specifies an id for every input method  so go to inspect and see what is the id of the image input